# Jfreechart add months instead of numbers

Tags: java, jfreechart

I would like to ask you a question.

I use Jfreechart,Could i add instead of numbers,months or string generally in my chart(for example:I want x line to be with months(string) and y with euros(integer)).Is it possible?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please have a look at the `org.jfree.demo.TimeSeriesChartDemo1` class that is included in the JFreeChart download. The source code is included in the source download of JFreeChart, so it's a good point to start with. I think that's what you want.

Update (revised on your comment):

You can change the format of axis labels by redefining the formatter.

In `TimeSeriesChartDemo1` there are two lines that define the format of the date axis. Change it as follows to show month names as labels only.

```
    DateAxis axis = (DateAxis)plot.getDomainAxis();
    axis.setDateFormatOverride(new SimpleDateFormat("MMM"));
```

Comment: Thank you very much Uli.I want something like this but without years.I want only months. :)
Ιn linechart demo 6 that i use is not allowed string but only numbers..:)

Comment: If you want a qualified answer please ask a qualified question :-) What are you trying exactly? What is the result? What do you expect or what do you want to change?

Comment: I'm sorry ,i'm not so specified.
I would like to have a chart that appears in x line only months(without years) and y line be like this that you sent me.

Comment: Τhank you very much Uli,I was so mindless.I have also another one question.

Comment: I call this class from a frame called basicframe.java  to my project and when i close the new frame( TimeSeriesChartDemo1.java  ),also close and my basicframe.java.how can i change the code to continue to my main frame(basicframe.java).
Thank you very much again.

Comment: This is not related to your initial question. So please mark this answer as your accepted answer. After that read the Stack Overflow tour (Help => Tour) to learn how to work with stack overflow. That's important because you disobey general guidelines of stack overflow. That's why most of your questions got a negative rating. At last post a new question. Thanks!

Comment: Read the Stack Overflow tour (Help => Tour)!! There is a checkmark on the left side of the answer. Pressing it changes the checkmark to green. Please read the Stack Overflow tour (Help => Tour)!!

Comment: Thank you for all of your information.If i would like to ask,how will i change the color of lines or the previous question,i must "ask question"